# Как изменить дизайн выпадающего списка?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

необходимо создать подобный выпадающий список ( можно без иконок/шрифтов/уголка) но именно с измененным закругленным блоком выбора варианта ответа, ибо option невозможно редактировать....вариант видимо должен содержать js

Comment: Вы какой фреймворк используете? На Bulma [**вот так**](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/#dropdown-content) это делается. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант.
Используется **Jquery**.

Так же добавлена возможность "взаимодействия" с `form`, через `input`.

```js
$('.select').on('click', '.placeholder', function() {
  $(this).closest('.select').toggleClass('drop');
}).on('click', '.option', function() {
  let parent = $(this).closest('.select'),
      selectVal = $(this).data('val') ? $(this).data('val') : ($(this).index() + 1),
      labeled = $(this).find('.labeled').text();
  parent.find('.option.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  parent.find('.placeholder').text(labeled);
  let parentID = '#for_' + parent.attr('id');
  $(parentID).val(selectVal);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css');
.select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.select .placeholder {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select .placeholder::before {
  content: '\f0d7';
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.select.drop>.placeholder::before {
  content: '\f0d8';
}

.select .option-list {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #aaa;
  background: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
}

.select .option-list::before,
.select .option-list::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.select .option-list::before {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #aaa;
  top: -20px;
  right: 10px;
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.select .option-list::after {
  border: 9.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  top: -17px;
  right: 11.5px;
}

.select .option {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select .option:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.select .option>i {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.select .option:first-child {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.select .option:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.select .option.selected {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.select.drop>.option-list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="select_1" class="select">
  <div class="placeholder">Transport</div>
  <div class="option-list">
    <div class="option" data-val="mail">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      <span class="labeled">Classic mail</span>
    </div>
    <div class="option" data-val="truck">
      <i class="fas fa-truck"></i>
      <span class="labeled">UPS Devilery</span>
    </div>
    <div class="option" data-val="jet">
      <i class="fas fa-plane"></i>
      <span class="labeled">Private jet</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="for_select_1" type="text">
```

В сниппете `input` показывается, чтобы визуально видеть изменения.
При использование данного кода замените `<input type="text">` на `<input type="hidden">`